# Fill jqgrid with data from visualforce page

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid, visualforce

I have a visualforce page and I am using jqgrid to display data on this page. The url that the jqgrid points to is a visualforce page(https://test.visual.force.com/apex/GridResults) which outputs only JSON data. This page does not have any header or html information.

The problem is that when I run this page, the grid renders with column names but no data.
When I run the url it outputs JSON data.  I have pasted below the code.

```
   jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:"https://test.visual.force.com/apex/GridResults",
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: [{!fieldNames}], -- property in controller  which outputs fieldnames 
        colModel: [{!colModel}], -- property in controller which outputs column definition
        rowNum: 10,
        rowTotal:10,
        rowList: [20, 40, 60],
        loadonce:true,
        mtype:"GET",
        gridView:true,
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'Record ID',
        sortorder: "desc",
        width: 1200,
        height: 400,
        caption: "Accounts"
    });  
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", { edit: true, add: true, del: false })
    };
```

Any ideas on why the data from the page is not consumed by the jqgrid? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to debug the javascript (i.e. using Firefox plugin "Firebug" or for IE simply putting "debugger;" statement somewhere in the javascript)? With Firebug you should be able to inspect headers (if any) and determine if data actually arrives. Also - how does jqgrid handle MIME types? Maybe it needs "application/json" and Salesforce outputs "text/html"?

Comment: One more: are you sure you don't need "jsonReader" or something similar? Check out the examples & warning at http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data , does your JSON match the required format?

Comment: thanks for your reply eyescream. Good point, i have'nt checked the mime type.  For now, I did a workaround by calling the visualforce controller using apex:actionFunction. when the data is returned, I build an array and pass it to the jqgrid! Works fine for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look into Visualforce remoting?